# Autoscaling on Plotting Histogram

Tags: netlogo

I understand this should autoscale. I am seeing this not happen though when implemented.

my code is simple:

```
histogram [xx] of turtles
```

I see that it is not capturing the large values of xx.

Answer (score 0):

That's right; autoscaling does not work for the X axis of a histogram. You can set the axis scales from your code; see the plotting commands. Remember that the highest bar in the histogram is greater than max [xx] of turtles.

I'm sure this has been discussed more thoroughly here previously; search the archives.

Comment: Is there some example. On the GUI for the plot, I don't see anywhere I can place the variables that I can create in the code.